# PHP web based scraper

Tags: php, html, scrape

What Im trying to do is use PHP to scrape a website of a url I enter into a parameter.

I want the whole raw source code.. But thats not all..

I want it then saved into an html page, and onto the local server of the php script.

Is there a Easy Snippet for this? or can someone easily write me up a code?

For example

I want to scrape http://google.com

So for instance, mysite.com/scrape.php?url=http://google.com

I want it to save the front page of google into http://mysite.com/scraped/google.com.html

Comment: By `scrape` you mean `download`?

Comment: How about looking into the documentation for `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a script that will save the contents of the specified url into a file named `scraped.html`:

```
if (isset($_GET['url'])):
   $contents = file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
   file_put_contents('scraped.html', $contents);
endif;
```

To use a url in the call to `file_get_contents()` you must enable [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) in your `php.ini` file.

Of course this will only save the actual source of the requested url and not any other resources, such as images, scripts and stylesheets.